# Android Studio - Design/preview window not displaying the layout and views added to the parent layout. I am using Mac

Tags: android, android-studio

I Cannot view the textview added to coordinator layout in android studio Design window. Please see the image attached. I am using mac OS sierra and android studio 3.0

Comment: where is the image?

Comment: close the layout manager and open it again

Comment: Vishal sorry the image did not get posted, @Oussema Aroua : had already tried that before. The issue was with the support appcompat library, I was using version 26.0.0 beta changed it to 25.1.3 and it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for replying, however solved the problem myself.
The issue was with android appcompat support library
I was using the Android O version that is 26.0.0 beta, when I changed that to 25.3.1 the preview/Design showed up.